# Создание триггера на добавление новой записи в таблицу postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, триггер

Коллеги, первый раз столкнулся с триггерами, требуется помощь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прочитал, что легче всего сделать заполнение второй таблицы (которая полностью зависит от первой), через триггер на инсерт в таблицу time.

То есть при добавлении новой записи (time_id) в таблицу time должна добавляться новая запись в таблице speed. Как это сделать?

Сам триггер создается примерно так:

CREATE TRIGGER rt_time_id__set_actual_speed_id

BEFORE INSERT ON time

FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE **new_row_function();**

Правильно ли? И если да, то что вписать в функцию new_row_function()?

Comment: А почему бы не вставлять в обе таблицы одним запросом? Постгресс вполне себе умеет...

Comment: Это пример таблиц. Но все гораздо сложнее, больше полей и просто так запросом при добавлении в одну таблицу, чтобы обновлялась и вторая - тут не обойтись

Comment: Да не смеши. INSERT прекрасно работает в CTE, есть RETURNING... какая разница, сколько там полей?